# oracle grant select right to a user with where clause

Tags: oracle

I should give username “Username1” read access to the “Product_id”, “Price” columns for all entries in the “Sales” table that have a “Price”> 10. Assume that the user exists and has the "Connect" role. The table exists in its schema.

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
Grant select(product_id, price) on sales where price > 10 to  ‘Username1’;
```

Comment: No, you cannot do it like this. You can either create a view, as the answer says, or you can create a virtual private db, it more complexe than creating a view, but can solve much more complicated cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS 
SELECT s.PRODUCT_ID, s.PRICE 
FROM SALES s
WHERE s.PRICE > 10
/
```

then use:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TEST TO USERNAME1
/
```

As far as I know You cannot add grant on strict column with where condition, but view can.